# Resolve stackdriver incident when no more timeseries with available data violate the policy

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-run

I have stackdriver alerts/incidents on metrics like cloud run revision request latencies.

If there were a few calls a long time ago that had high latency, but there have not been any new requests since then which had a low latency, the incident will be permanently firing. This is because when there are no new requests coming in, there are no data points for the metric.

Is there a way to automatically stop an incident from firing when there are no recent data points for the underlying metrics? Or is there an alternative way to have alerts on high request latencies in cloud run that automatically switches off the alarm again when no new requests are coming that have a high latency?

Comment: Hi, could you please provide more details (e.g documentation, playbook etc.) which you have followed to achieve your desired output. However, you can take a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth) that explains about the behavior of the alerting policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: This solution will not work because the request count stops being sent to Stackdriver instead of dropping to zero. As explained in the [other (more correct) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64294533), the solution is to create a logs-based metric for the requests, and this will properly drop to zero when there are no additional requests.

---

This behaviour is documented in the [alerting docs](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth#partial-metric-data):

> If measurements are missing (for example, if there are no HTTP
> requests for a couple of minutes), the policy uses the last recorded
> value to evaluate conditions.

There are a few recommendations in there to mitigate this issue, but all the suggestions assume you're actually collecting metrics, not your situation where there are no metrics at all (because you stopped receiving requests).

This is probably by design: even if you are not receiving additional requests, you might still want to check why all the latest requests had this increased latency.

To work around this feature, you could try to use [multiple conditions](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth#condition-combiners) in your alert policy:

- One condition related to the latency: if latency > X
- One condition related to the existence of requests: if request count > 1

If you combine those with `AND_WITH_MATCHING_RESOURCE`, it should only trigger if there's high latency *and* there are requests. The incident should be resolved when one of the 2 conditions are not met. Even if no new metrics are ingested related to the latency (so the alerting policy still thinks the latency is high), the request count will stop matching after the duration period specified.

[image: alert config]

Answer (score 1):

The solution of https://stackoverflow.com/a/63997540/6473907 does not work as-is, because the google cloud run built-in metric for the request count does not go to zero when there are no more requests coming in. Instead, it just stops providing any data points. The solution for us was to create a custom logs-based metric that counts the log entries written for every request by cloud run, because the logs-based metric does indeed go to zero, then combine it with the `AND_WITH_MATCHING_RESOURCE` as described in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63997540/6473907

The chart compares the request count as obtained from the google pre-defined metric run.googleapis.com/request_count (in violet) with the metric generated by a custom logs-based metric (in blue). Only the latter goes to zero when no more requests are coming in.

[image]